# python3 recursion print digit does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to use recursion (basically recall the function) and print the digit of the number, but I can not use str, and this function can not return anything, I am thinking why does my function wrong and how to actually fix it...
I am thinking really hard but if I can't use string I wont able to print this
function should have a num as a parameter and example will be 12345
and run into the function the python should print

```
5
4
3
2
1

def printDigit(num):
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return num
    print(num % 10)
    return printDigit(num//10)

printDigit(12345)
```

Comment: Don't edit your question. Your are making it difficult.

Comment: your code runs fine in command prompt.

Comment: Is the output you show correct? If not, please edit the question to add in the correct output.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you're not printing the last digit (because there's no `print()` before the base case return).

Comment: @dfundako Sure? Does it print the first digit?

Answer (score 1):

You do not print your base case, but instead return it, so the final value in your function will not be printed without an explicit call to print.

```
def printDigit(num):
    print(num % 10)
    num //= 10
    if num != 0:
      printDigit(num)

printDigit(12345)
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Here is what your code does in a REPL:

```
In [1]: def printDigit(num):
   ...:     if num // 10 == 0:
   ...:         return num
   ...:     print(num % 10)
   ...:     return printDigit(num//10)
   ...:
   ...: printDigit(12345)
   ...:
5
4
3
2
Out[1]: 1
```

As you can see, `1` here is not being printed, but instead returned.  In many Python interactive shells, the result of a function is printed, which is why your output may *look* correct in a shell.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, because IDLE will output the result of his function call, without an explicit print.